# The difference between object[] = object[] f = new object[] and var f = new []?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I'm a newbee of C#, and I want use anonymous-types in a recent project, but I face a confuse problem which need your help.
I use the object[] at first but I get a error. The code is showed below:

```
        List<object> f = new List<object>(); 
        f.Add(new { Name = 1, Age = 31 });
        f.Add(new { Name = 2, Age = 31 });
        f.Add(new { Name = 3, Age = 4 });
        f.Add(new { Name = 4, Age = 1 });
        f.Add(new { Name = 5, Age = 1 });
        var a = f[0].Age; // no use
```

But this code is useful：

```
    var f = new []
    {
        new { Name = 1, Age = 31 },
        new { Name = 2, Age = 31 },
        new { Name = 3, Age = 4 },
        new { Name = 4, Age = 1 },
        new { Name = 5, Age = 1 }
    };
    var a = f[0].Age;
```

I just want to use a anonymous-type List and access it's members.
What's wrong with my method and what should I do to achieve my target?

Comment: An `Object` has no `Age` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem is because you're using anonymous types (but maybe this is OK, since you're trying to use them in the first place) you can't actually declare or pass around this list (How do you declare `List<SomeAnonymousTypeThatDoesNotHaveAName>`?)

You can use generics and cheat though by taking advantage of generic type inference and `var`:

```
public List<T> BuildList<T>(params T[] entries)
{
    return new List<T>(entries);
}
```

When you call `BuildList`, again because they're anonymous types, you cannot explicitly assign `<T>`, but you can let type inference handle it!

```
var list = BuildList(
    new { Name = 1, Age = 31 },
    new { Name = 2, Age = 31 },
    new { Name = 3, Age = 4 },
    new { Name = 4, Age = 1 },
    new { Name = 5, Age = 1 });
```

Type inference handles the anonymous type just fine and builds your list!

```
Console.WriteLine(list.Count); //5
Console.WriteLine(list[0].Name + ", " + list[0].Age); //1, 31
Console.WriteLine(list.GetType().FullName); //System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], query_jyattd, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

EDIT: Even better is to make an extension method!

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static List<T> MakeAnonymousList<T>(this T[] entries)
    {
        return new List<T>(entries);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
var list = new[] {
    new { Name = 1, Age = 31 },
    new { Name = 2, Age = 31 },
    new { Name = 3, Age = 4 },
    new { Name = 4, Age = 1 },
    new { Name = 5, Age = 1 }}
    .MakeAnonymousList();
```

EDIT: The cool thing is that you have a fully functional `List<T>` that you can add/remove/Linq on. Adding items *must* be done with the same parameters and order:

```
list.Add(new { Name = 6, Age = 2 }); //OK
list.Add(new { Age = 2, Name = 6 }); //compile error!


var maxAge = list.Max(person => person.Age);
var oldPerson = list.Where(person => person.Age == maxAge).First();
Console.WriteLine(maxAge); //31
Console.WriteLine(oldPerson.Name + ", " + oldPerson.Age); //1, 31
```

Intellisense works great too!

Comment: No need to create `MakeAnonymousList<T>`: The extension method [`IEnumerable<T>.ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) already exists!

Comment: @Heinzi Well don't I feel sheepish... Serves me right for jumping on SO before my morning coffee.

Answer (score 5):

An `Object` has no `Age` property. Hence the first approach doesn't compile since you have boxed the anonymous type as object.

The second works because the compiler knows which (anonymous) type it is.

You cannot use an anonymous type outside of the current method. I would suggest to use a concrete type therefore.

```
class Person
{
    public int Age{ get;set; }
    public string Name{ get;set; }
}
```

and now use that:

```
var f = new List<Person>(){
             new Person{ Name = "1", Age = 31 },
             new Person{ Name = "2", Age = 31 },
             new Person{ Name = "3", Age = 4 },
             new Person{ Name = "4", Age = 1 },
             new Person{ Name = "5", Age = 1 }
};
var a = f[0].Age;
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** - updated answer. Original answer is at the end.

Following doesnot work

```
List<object> f = new List<object>();
```

because object has no `Age` property.

To get Age property, you need to typecast into concrete type. But since you have used anonymous type, you dont have concrete type at coding time (and hence you cannot cast it).

Another (discouraged) alternative  is the use of `reflection`

```
 PropertyInfo[] properties = f[0].GetType().GetProperties();
 var ageProperty = properties.First (x=> x.Name == "Age");
 var a = ageProperty.GetValue (f[0],null); // no use
```

Yet another alternative (if it is .NET 4.0 and above) is to use keyword [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx).

```
   dynamic obj = f[0];
   int age = obj.Age;
   Console.WriteLine(age); // prints 31
```

---

**Original answer**

change

```
object[] f = new object[]
```

to

```
 var f = new []
```

and first one will work.

Comment: @Jun, Seems you have changed the question after my answer. Wait for Edit